# Need help figuring out how to write promise with conditional

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, bluebird

This is what I'm trying to do

```
isAuthorized(params){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(params.property){
       doSomething().then(function(e){
         if(e){
            resolve(true);
         } else {
           reject(false);
         }
    } else {
      doSomethingElse().then(function(e){
         if(e){
            resolve(true);
         } else {
           reject(false);
         }
    }
}
```

but I get a warning: "a promise was created at handler but was not returned from" while the function does as intended.

I have also tried

```
isAuthorized(params){
  if(params.property){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       doSomething().then(function(e){
         if(e){
            resolve(true);
         } else {
           reject(false);
         }
    });
  } else {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      doSomethingElse().then(function(e){
         if(e){
            resolve(true);
         } else {
           reject(false);
         }
    });
  }
}
```

let me know if you need any more info.. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/warning-explanations.md#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it

It's complaining that you aren't returning the inner `doSomething()` promise anywhere. To avoid the promise-callback anti-pattern, try something like this instead:

```
function isAuthorized(params) {
  function resolveIfTruthy(e) {
    if (e) return Promise.resolve(true);
    else return Promise.reject(false);
  }
  if (params.property) {
    return doSomething()
      .then(resolveIfTruthy);
  } else {
    return doSomethingElse()
      .then(resolveIfTruthy);
  }
}
```

Comment: I was about to write very similar answer. It isn't necessary to introduce named function. This can be achieved with `const promise = params.property ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse(); return promise.then(e => { if (e) return true; else throw false; })`